# how remove the element with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have some buttons in a php while loop and the buttons have a onClick method. I would like delete the button what I pick.

This is my code on the button:

```
while($row = $query->fetch_assoc())
{
   $Var1= $row ['Id'];
   $Description= $row ['Description'];
   $Detail= $row ['Detail'];
                    ?>
   <button class="btn btn-danger btn-block" onClick="Hello('<?php echo $Var1; ?>','Delete')">
      <div class="pull-left first">
         <i class="fa fa-bell" aria-hidden="true"></i> <?php echo ucwords($Description); ?>
      </div>
      <div class="pull-left notification">
         <?php echo ucfirst($Detail); ?> 
      </div>
   </button>
}
```

And this is the code what I was trying on my js

```
function Hello(ID,Action){


$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    data: {"Action":Action,"ID":ID},
    url: 'Pages/Actions.php',
    success: function(data)
    {

        switch (data) 
        { 
            case '1': 
                    $('#Fail').html('<p class="alert alert-warning"><i class="fa fa-exclamation-triangle" aria-hidden="true"></i> Empty Fields</p>');
                    $('#Success').html('');
                break;
            case '2': 
                    $('#Fail').html('<p class="alert alert-danger"><i class="fa fa-bug" aria-hidden="true"></i> Fail</p>');
                    $('#Success').html('');
                break;
            case '3'                                                                  
                    $('#Fail').html('');
                    $('#Success').html(''); 
                    $(this).remove();
                break;      
            default:
            alert(data);
        }
    }
});
return false;
}
```

My jQuery is really basic so, if you can give me some recomendations will be awesome

Comment: can you post all the code of your button please ? ( and where are you putting the jquery code to remove it ? )

Comment: @Taki I update my question thank you for your time :D

Comment: In _this_ case, I think $(this).remove() is based in the $.AJAX not in the BUTTON, Try to move `$(this).remove()` to another place like adding a global var `var isSuccess = false` and then in `case '3': /* code */ isSuccess = true;` So, after the $.ajax you can test if the var "isSuccess" is true, then, just remove with `$(this).remove()`. Check if this works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first, as Aibol Orazbekov suggest, you should use class names to launch specific function.

My recommandations are :

- don't use `onClick` parameter
- you should use dataset to pass variables to Javascript's functions
- you should use HTTP codes to handle errors (and use jQuery's ajax `error()` function to handle them)
- don't use uppercase for your simple variables names. Use it only for constants

To answer your question, `$(this)` doesn't link to your element.

Based on your code, and using class names, you can try something like this :

HTML/PHP

```
while($row = $query->fetch_assoc())
{
   $var1= $row ['Id'];
   $description= $row ['Description'];
   $detail= $row ['Detail'];
                    ?>
   <button class="btn btn-danger btn-block btn-action" data-id="<?php echo $var1; ?>" data-action="Delete">
      <div class="pull-left first">
         <i class="fa fa-bell" aria-hidden="true"></i> <?php echo ucwords($description); ?>
      </div>
      <div class="pull-left notification">
         <?php echo ucfirst($detail); ?> 
      </div>
   </button>
}
```

JS

```
$('.btn-action').on('click', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var elt = $(this);  // save button element in a variable

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        data: {
            Action: elt.data('action'),  // use dataset here ...
            ID: elt.data('id')           // ... and here
        },
        url: 'Pages/Actions.php',
        success: function(data)
        {

            switch (data) 
            { 
                case '1': 
                        $('#Fail').html('<p class="alert alert-warning"><i class="fa fa-exclamation-triangle" aria-hidden="true"></i> Empty Fields</p>');
                        $('#Success').html('');
                    break;
                case '2': 
                        $('#Fail').html('<p class="alert alert-danger"><i class="fa fa-bug" aria-hidden="true"></i> Fail</p>');
                        $('#Success').html('');
                    break;
                case '3'                                                                  
                        $('#Fail').html('');
                        $('#Success').html(''); 
                        elt.remove();  // this is your error
                    break;      
                default:
                alert(data);
            }
        }
    });
    return false;
}
```

I hope this help

Comment: Thank you a lot for that, I have to study all you comment, I don't know why doen't work with `var elt = $(this) elt.remove();`, but for now I solve my problem adding a id to the button concatenating with the $Id of the row,  `id="Delete<?php echo $ID; ?>"` and on the function, I put $('#Delete'+ID ).... it works for now but I want to have better practices so thanks for all you comment :D @micster

Answer (score 1):

Separate your event functions from html code. Its a good practice.
So first, your ids should be unique, so create a class for your buttons.

```js
$('.some-class').on('click', function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  $(this).remove();
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class = "some-class">Button</button>
```

You can try the code. It should work

Comment: Sorry I update my question thank you for your time :D

Answer (score 1):

Prior to ES6

Back then suicide was not allowed, only parent elements were allowed to kill their child.

```
this.parentNode.removeChild(this)
```

ES6 and beyond

```
this.remove()
```

JQuery

```
$( selector ).remove()
```

Comment: Hello @Mike !! Sorry, I update my question thank you for your time :D

Comment: This code is still valid to remove your element OnClick event.

Comment: If you use it in jQuery's callback, then 'this' references changes. In that case you should save this in other variable before ajax call like: var that = this;  then use 'that' instead

Comment: My jQuery or AJAX is really basic :x, I try what you say but throw me this error  ** Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read this property removeChild of undefined**, I used the code you gave me like that:  `function hello(ID,action){
 var that = this;
this.parentNode.removeChild(that);}`